# Save Read Unity3d c# Google Firebase ServerValue.Timestamp

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to save Server.Timestamp to my Firebase database unity3d c#. I have tried several methods but failed to get the result. From Google Firebase example I can see that timestamp is saved as a long https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/structure-data
but none of their example really deals with saving this value or reading this value.

```
"chats": {
    "one": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
      "timestamp": 1459361875666
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },
```

I failed to find a single simple example to save and read servervalue.timestamp.
Basically I would like to know how to save and use Google Firebase ServerValue.Timestamp in c#.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your unity application you create the JSON that you want to send where you replace the timestamp value by something like :

```
"chats": {
    "one": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
      "timestamp": {".sv" : "timestamp"}
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
    },
```

Then the server will replace

```
{".sv" : "timestamp"}
```

by

```
1459361875666 // current server date
```

and you'll be able to read the "timestamp" field as a long

Here's a working example:

```
        Dictionary<string, object> scoreUpdate = new Dictionary<string, object> ();
        Dictionary<string, object> timestamp = new Dictionary<string, object> ();
        timestamp [".sv"] = "timestamp";
        scoreUpdate ["scores/" + userID + "/name"] = name;
        scoreUpdate ["scores/" + userID + "/score"] = -score;
        scoreUpdate ["scores/" + userID + "/time/"] = timestamp;

        DBRef.Root ().UpdateChildrenAsync (scoreUpdate);
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please show a very simple example with which we can do this in c#. I tried several ways but it did not get saved as a long.